# Is this a sufficient condition for a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory

Im pretty sure this is a sufficient (and maybe even necessary but I'm not bothered too much with that) condition for a martingale:

$\mathbb{E}[\frac{X_t}{X_s} | \mathcal{F}_s] = 1 a.s $ for all $t > s$?

The proof is simple. If this holds then as $X_s  \text{is}   \mathcal{F}_s$ measurable we can simply factorise it out? Leaving us with $\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s] = X_s a.s$

Comment: What if $\mathsf{P}(X_s=0)>0$?

Comment: @d.k.o. oooo that is so true. anyway to get around that?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "get around that"? If it's really important to you to construct a condition that looks like this, you'll just have to exclude that case specifically -- that is, "For all processes $X_t$ such that $\mathbb P(X_t = 0) = 0$ for all $t$, if $\mathbb E \left[ \frac{X_t}{X_s} \mid \mathcal F_s \right] = 1$ a.s. for $t > s$, then the process is a martingale." That statement is true, and you gave the proof of it. But the "way to get around it" would just be to give the proper definition instead of this one, I suppose.